# If I knead my dough long and fast enough, can it be cooked itself?

Tags: food-chemistry, mechanochemistry

May be Seasoned Advice question, but I thought that it's more of a scientific question. Correct me if I was wrong.

Kneading generates friction between dough chemicals(gluten, starch, etc.), thus generating heat. That's why we constantly chill pastry dough because the heat originated from the dough can ruin butter-dough layers AFAIK.

So... will that heat eventually cook the dough? Will it be heated enough to cook itself?

Comment: This is pretty much the same as "can you cook a chicken by slapping it". Answer is... not really.

Comment: @orthocresol Good point. I thought that if a chicken is slapped many times it can also be counted as some sort of... liquidy... doughy... goo, and that if I knead or blend that "dough" long enough, it can also be cooked by friction heat, if we can still call it a chicken. Dough does not have that concrete form, so dough will still be dough when deformed and then heated.

Comment: All depends on scenario. If you used n kW electric engine, thermally isolated space and properly geared mixing device, the dough would get surely baked, with mechanical power converted to thermal power. If the same mechanical power is used as thermal power needed to keep baking temperature (for the same arrangement), mechanical baking is possible. // Practical use is another question.

Comment: Also, long before the dough would be cooked, it would be reduced to a dried-out crumbling mass. However, *friction stir welding* is effective: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction_stir_welding . So, you could weld the stirrer to the metal bowl...

Comment: Good comment, as intensive stirring would cause intensive drying out, unless there is closed space and limited air volume.

Comment: No, if you consider heat transfer the bread will never get warm enough to actually heat up/bake.